# Getting a connection error on Elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I was making a connection to the elasticsearch and can not understand why I'm getting this error. This happens every time I type into the python interpreter.

```
>>> from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
>>> es = Elasticsearch('http://localhost:9200')
>>> es.index(index='my_index', id=1, body={'text': 'this is a test'})
```

elasticsearch.exceptions.ConnectionError: ConnectionError

Comment: Are you sure the elasticsearch service is running?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`es = Elasticsearch([{'host': 'localhost', 'port': 9200}])`

Comment: Thanks but still facing the same problem.